# Apps script, instead of get the range values, i get "Loading..." depite all is well display

Tags: javascript, csv, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I work on this range :
[image]

The currency are display with a formula and as you can see, all is well display.

I got this problem suddenly, i didn't have it before.
When i try to get the values of this range :

```
const sheet = Sheet(1)
const range = sheet.getRange(RANGE_C)
const values = range.getDisplayValues()
```

I get an array with if i get the values with getValues : #ERROR and with getDisplayValues : "Loading..."  :

[ [ 'Chargement en cours...',
'0,00 €',
'Chargement en cours...',
'Chargement en cours...',
'Chargement en cours...',
'Chargement en cours...',
'Chargement en cours...',
'Chargement en cours...',
'8',
'8',
'0',
'0',
'14',
'14',
'0',
'0' ],  etc]

Comment: Try adding a new line with `SpreadsheetApp.flush()` before getting the values

Comment: Thank you so much  Can you put it as answer for i accept it please ? ))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the result of calculations aren't shown in Google Apps Script, you can use `SpreadsheetApp.flush()` that waits until the calculations are done and then retrieves the desired information

For future users that come to this post to find other possible solutions: if it happens with formulas that include IMPORTRANGE it may not be enough, so what I've done to solve it is to modify some cell (inside the script) that is included in the formula or formulas that are included in my range. When that's not possible, what I did is to destinate a cell as the "update cell" that will not affect the formulas but will let me update the values and wait for its refresh with SpreadsheetApp.flush()

For example, if I have a formula that says:

```
=IMPORTRANGE("....","Sheet1!A:C")
```

then I will change it to:

```
=LET(updatecell,Z1,
IMPORTRANGE("....","Sheet1!A:C"))
```

And then, inside the code:

```
sheet.getRange("Z1").setValue(new Date())
SpreadsheetApp.flush()
```

This "update cell" won't affect any of the formulas included, but as they're "inside" of the formulas they'll be forced to update and show the values after "flush()". Obviously, I set Z1 as the cell, but you can change it to any other cell that doesn't bother you

DISCLAIMER: it fails about 1 to 5% of the times... it's some major issue from Google, but at least it will let you solve it most of the times