# Script is pasting data as #N/A rather than the value

Tags: arrays, function, google-apps-script, google-sheets, append

I am using the following script to copy data from one sheet and paste to the last row of another.

```
function menuItem1() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var srcSheet = ss.getSheetByName("HOME");
  var dstSheet = ss.getSheetByName("HISTORY");

  var data_range = srcSheet.getRange('O4:FX100'); 
  var data_data = data_range.getValues();
  var data_clean  = data_data.filter(function (r) {return r[0]});

  var F4toF100 = srcSheet.getRange('F4:F100');
  var H4toH100 = srcSheet.getRange('H4:H100');
  var D3toD6 = srcSheet.getRange('D3:D6');

  var text1 = dstSheet.getRange('A2:EY100');
  var date2 = dstSheet.getRange('EZ2:EZ100');
  var text3 = dstSheet.getRange('FA2:FD100');
  var number4 = dstSheet.getRange('FE2:FE100');
  var number5 = dstSheet.getRange('FF2:FF100');
  var number6 = dstSheet.getRange('FG2:FG100');
  var text7 = dstSheet.getRange('FH2:FH100');
  var number8 = dstSheet.getRange('FI2:FJ100');

  var lr = dstSheet.getLastRow(); 

  dstSheet.getRange(lr+1, 1,data_clean.length,166).setValues(data_clean);

  text1.setNumberFormat("@");
  date2.setNumberFormat('dd/MM/yyyy');
  text3.setNumberFormat("@");
  number4.setNumberFormat('#.##');
  number5.setNumberFormat('%');
  number6.setNumberFormat('#.##');
  text7.setNumberFormat("@");
  number8.setNumberFormat('#.##');

  F4toF100.clearContent();
  H4toH100.clearContent();
  D3toD6.clearContent();    
}
```

The srcSheet can contain anything from 1 to 100 rows.
The example data I am using is 51 rows.
When I run the script, it copies the data to a new sheet, but columns FF, FG and FJ appear as #N/A, when they should be percentage, number and number respectively.

Advice from an expert user suggests this is because:
"Range.setValues()expects a 2D array, but your filter function is converting data_clean to a 1D array, which makes Range.setValues() throw an error."

I use this script A LOT and have never experienced this error before, even with cells formatted exactly the same way as the sheet I am using in this example, so I don't understand why the error is appearing on this sheet and not others.

Comment: Does the source data  contain ``=Googlefinance()`` formulas??

Comment: @TheMaster If my understanding of your comment is correct, in the current stage, it seems that the cell values retrieved by `GOOGLEFINANCE` can be retrieved instead of `#N/A` by Google Spreadsheet service (SpreadsheetApp) and Sheets API. https://stackoverflow.com/a/46028979 But, if I misunderstood your comment, I apologize.

Comment: @TheMaster  - no it doesn't contain any data from =Googlefinance().

Comment: In your situation,  for example, the values of `data_clean` includes `#N/A`?

Comment: @Tanaike - No. Only 3 columns of the 166 being copied produce the #N/A error. None of these three columns contain the result #N/A. Column1 is a percentage calculate using IF and VLOOKUP. Columns 2 & 3 are numbers calculated from other columns on the same sheet. Yet, I have other columns that have more or less the same type of formulas in that display the results correctly.

Comment: @TheMaster Welcome! Actually, I was surprised when I noticed it. But, I think that the specification might have been changed because I can confirm that the cell values of `GOOGLEFINANCE` can be retrieved now.

Comment: If you click on N/A, it'll show the reason, a error message for N/A. Update your question with that information/ screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

You may have a situation similar to this if those cells include results of calculations or imported ranges. Please try the approaches I suggested in [this post:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76594174/apps-script-instead-of-get-the-range-values-i-get-loading-depite-all-is-w/76595899#76595899)

When the result of calculations aren't shown in Google Apps Script, you can use `SpreadsheetApp.flush()` that waits until the calculations are done and then retrieves the desired information

For future users that come to this post to find other possible solutions: if it happens with formulas that include IMPORTRANGE it may not be enough, so what I've done to solve it is to modify some cell (inside the script) that is included in the formula or formulas that are included in my range. When that's not possible, what I did is to destinate a cell as the "update cell" that will not affect the formulas but will let me update the values and wait for its refresh with SpreadsheetApp.flush()

For example, if I have a formula that says:

```
=IMPORTRANGE("....","Sheet1!A:C")
```

then I will change it to:

```
=LET(updatecell,Z1,
IMPORTRANGE("....","Sheet1!A:C"))
```

And then, inside the code:

```
sheet.getRange("Z1").setValue(new Date())
SpreadsheetApp.flush()
```

This "update cell" won't affect any of the formulas included, but as they're "inside" of the formulas they'll be forced to update and show the values after "flush()". Obviously, I set Z1 as the cell, but you can change it to any other cell that doesn't bother you

DISCLAIMER: it fails about 1 to 5% of the times... it's some major issue from Google, but at least it will let you solve it most of the times

Comment: thanks for your detailed explanation. However, I am not using IMPORTRANGE on the columns that are creating an error. They are however pulling data from other columns on the sheet, using arrayformulas. I'm not sure how to adapt your solution to work in this case.

Comment: You can try the same approach, using LET and some cell you choose: =LET(updatecell,Z1,
ARRAYFORMULA(.........)) - Remember to then update the value of that cell in the code and do a SpreadsheetApp.flush() - you can also change Z1 with some named range, if it'd make it more reliable

Comment: unfortunately the solution hasn't worked.